# how to map numbers to a three color scale with D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to map numbers from -1 to 1 to a continuous color scale ranging from orange to blue, **with 0 mapped to white**.

```
var corr_color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-1, 1])
    .range(["#FF6600", "#3399FF"]);
```

The above code would map 0 to a brownish color.
Any advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales), you should just be able to add in another value for white. Does that not work?

```
.domain([-1, 0, 1])
.range(["#FF6600", "#FFFFFF", "#3399FF"]);
```

Made this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3n90gyuj/1/)

Comment: Awesome! You may be interested in [this article](https://vis4.net/blog/posts/mastering-multi-hued-color-scales/) for some more information on creating color scales